# How to render my Components conditionally in React ? I don't know if this is a proper title based on my problem

Tags: node.js, reactjs, error-handling, rendering

So, I've been working on a small project where I use coinmarketcap.com API to get cryptocurrency's data and display them as a table inside the Webpage. I am using Node.js as backend.

I managed to get data from API and display as table. Here's my problem- I want to display the cryptocurrency prices in 2 currency values. So I used a switch. So, when switch is `true` I want to render table with prices in USD. And when switch is `false` I want to render the table with prices in INR.

Here is my code.

```
function Home() {

const [coins,setCoins]=useState([])
const [search,setSearch]=useState("")
const [switchState,setSwitchState]=useState(true)
const [currency,setCurrency]=useState("USD")

//Here's my API call. I set currency="USD" or "INR" based on the change of event in my Bootstrap switch

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(`http://localhost:9000/api/${currency}`).then(
                                (response)=>{
                                    setCoins([])
                                    setCoins(response.data)
                                })
},[])

//This function is for filtering search
const filterCoins=coins.filter
(
       coin => coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    )

return (
    <>
    <div className="container">
     <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-5 d-flex mt-3">
        <input className="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" onChange={
                (e)=>{setSearch(e.target.value)}
                }/>
            <div className="ml-5">

//This is the Switch where I set currency="USD" or "INR"

            <BootstrapSwitchButton
                checked={switchState}
                onlabel='USD'
                offlabel='INR'
                onChange={(event)=>{
                    setSwitchState(event)
                        if(switchState==true){
                            setCurrency("USD")
                            console.log(switchState)                            
                        }else{
                            setCurrency("INR") 
                            console.log(switchState)
                        }
                    }}/>

            </div>
        </div>

        <table className="table table-secondary table-bordered table-striped mt-3">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td className="fw-bold" >Coin</td>
        <td className="fw-bold">CryptoName</td>
        <td className="fw-bold">Price</td>
        <td className="fw-bold">24Hr Change</td>
        <td className="fw-bold">Market Cap</td>
        <td className="fw-bold">24Hr Volume</td>
        </tr>
//This is where I import rows from my Coin component based on the Switch state(whether true or false)
         {   switchState?(
              filterCoins.map((coin)=>{
                return(
               <Coin
               key={coin.id}
               name={coin.name}
               symbol={coin.symbol} 
               price={coin.quote.USD.price}
               change24hr={coin.quote.USD.percent_change_24h}
               marketCap={coin.quote.USD.market_cap}
               vol24hr={coin.quote.USD.volume_24h}/>
                )
            })

             ):(
                filterCoins.map((coin)=>{
                    return(
                   <Coin
                   key={coin.id}
                   name={coin.name}
                   symbol={coin.symbol} 
                   price={coin.quote.INR.price}
                   change24hr={coin.quote.INR.percent_change_24h}
                   marketCap={coin.quote.INR.market_cap}
                   vol24hr={coin.quote.INR.volume_24h}/>
                    )
                })
               
             )
        }

        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </>
)
export default Home
}
```

Here's the error I am getting:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMYgq.jpg)

The thing is this code displays table with USD price. But, as soon as I use Switch, it gives me this error.

I know that is a bit much to go through. But, kindly help me anyone. Please.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: looking in error it seems INR is undefined. Do `console.log(coin.quote)` and update the question.

Comment: your error tells that `coin.quote.USD` is undefined.so do this:
useEffect(()=>{console.log(coin.quote.USD)},[coin]) and tell what you get

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I just figured out that useEffect() only rendered at the initial stage. So, it didnt call the api whenever I changed the switch. So I used seperate states for storing USD and INR values. And used useEffect() seperately for both. And it worked. Thank you all for trying to help. I appreciate it.